# Issue while adding many to one relationship with Flask, SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

First of all, bear with me as I'm very new to Python/Flask and SQLAlchemy. I'm trying to create a one to many relationship between two models, here are they:

```
class Stock(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'stocks'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    users = db.relationship('User', secondary=user_identifier)
    historical_prices = db.relationship('HistoricalPrice', backref='stock', lazy=True)

class HistoricalPrice(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'historical_prices'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    stock_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('stock.id'), nullable=False)
```

Please note that there is a relationship between `User` and `Stock` which currently works fine. The issue I'm having is between `Stock` and `HistoricalPice`.

After I have done the migration and update, in my code I have:

```
stock = Stock.query.last()
historical = HistoricalPrice(name='Test')
stock.historical_prices.append(historical)
```

But then I get the following error: `sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Stock.historical_prices - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.`

I used the info on this [page](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/models/) to create the relationship.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misspelled the table name in `ForeignKey`:

```
stock_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('stocks.id'), nullable=False)
```

Your table is named `stocks`, not `stock`.

Comment: stocks.id instead of stock.id

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe it was such a silly mistake! I'll mark as answer in 5 mins (its not allowing me not mark yet)

Comment: Weird. Now I'm getting a new error: `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "historical_prices" does not exist`. Also when I load the database using Postico, I cannot see the new table `historical_prices` even though I have issue the following commands: `python manage.py db migrate` and `python manage.py db upgrade`. Any ideas? Should I manually create the table?